# Python SQlite returning an Object rather than a string

Tags: python, arrays, sqlite

I'm trying to create a support ticket system using flask. I am using sqlite3 for my database of tickets. I am trying to get all of the 'ids' of tickets with a status of 'pending' however when I run the said function it returns `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x03746B20>` is their anyway I can fetch all of the ids as an array of strings?

Function:

```
def GetPendingTickets():
  opendb()
  qry = "SELECT 'id' FROM 'tickets' WHERE 'Status'='Pending'"
  connection.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
  openTickets = cursor.execute(qry)
  closedb()
  return openTickets
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, yes I tried fetchall however it only returned "[]", I know that there is at least one ticket with the status "pending" because I can see it in the database (im using a database viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the quotes leaves open the question, why to do that.

Well, quoting is a bit clumsy in SQL. String literals are quoted with single quotes like in `'pending'` (always mandatory), while field and table names may be quoted in double quotes like in `"tickets"`, but this is only mandatory, when the field names contain strange characters or are case-sensitive. You were heavily working with string literals, but this is not your intention. you can write

```
qry = """SELECT "id" FROM "tickets" WHERE "Status" = 'Pending'"""
```

or, minimizing quotes, write

```
qry = """SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE "Status" = 'Pending'"""
```

when the field name of the status field is really "Status" and not "STATUS" (you would have created the table with quotes in that case).

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [fetchall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall), [fetchone](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone)  or [fetchmany](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany) after the execute:

```
iIn [1]: import sqlite3

In [2]: con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

In [3]: cur = con.cursor()

In [4]: cur.executescript("""
   ...:     create table person(
   ...:         firstname,
   ...:         lastname,
   ...:         age
   ...:     );
   ...: 
   ...:     create table book(
   ...:         title,
   ...:         author,
   ...:         published
   ...:     );
   ...: 
   ...:     insert into book(title, author, published)
   ...:     values (
   ...:         'Dirk Gently''s Holistic Detective Agency',
   ...:         'Douglas Adams',
   ...:         1987
   ...:     );
   ...:     """)
Out[4]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x7f1eac026ce0>

In [5]: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `book`")
Out[5]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x7f1eac026ce0>

In [6]: cur.fetchall()
[(u"Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency", u'Douglas Adams', 1987)]
```

Also change your query:

```
qry = "SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE Status = 'Pending'"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried .fetchal(), and it returned [], I know there is at least one row, where status = pending (I am using an Database Viewer)

Comment: Why are you wrapping the query strings in quotes?

Comment: Because that is what I naturally did, I have now removed them, and it worked, thanks

Comment: The column names should not be wrapped in strings, just the row value if that is stored as a string. You're welcome.